# Nested Loop - Is This Bad Practice

Tags: javascript, node.js

Would it be bad practice to perform a loop like this?  I'm looping through all cars and appending the text 'new' to each color's name.  Each car can have multiple colors.

```
var cars = [
    {
        company: "honda",
        colors: [
            {
                name="burntRed"
            },
            {
                name: "springGreen"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        company: "ford",
        colors: [
            {
                name="burntOrange"
            },
            {
                name: "black"
            }
        ]
    }
];
        for (var c = 0; c < cars.length; p++) {

            var car = cars[c];

            for (var i = 0; i < cars.colors.length; i++) {
                car.color[i].name += 'new ' + car.color[i].name;
            };
        };
```

Comment: I assume `cars.colors.length` was supposed to be `car.colors.length`?

Comment: It is a bad practice to write objects as `{name="burntOrange"}`. But the loops are fine (at least, given this little info)

Comment: Typos aside, if you want to touch every car and every color inside every car, then yeah, you need two loops. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the general practice you're showing. There are a few mistakes in your code that will prevent it from working; the one I noticed was that I think you want `=`, not `+=` (near the end). @MattBurland He's asking if this is a bad practice. Sometimes an intangible coding sense suggests to one's self that there might be a better way of doing something, but in this case there's no obvious alternative solution.

Comment: Sergio why is that bad?

Comment: @WeDoTDD: because it rarely works! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the data structure you are iterating over is nested, I do not see another (more performant) way to achieve your task.
Nested iterations are not necessarily a bad thing. Even many well-known algorithms rely on them. But you have to be extremely cautious what you execute in the deepest loop, since these commands will be performed very often.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider a different style to loop over the arrays. Javascript offer a variety of looping methods of [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Here is an example of your proposed functionality, here you can spot the more cleaner style, because of the not more needed index variable.

By the way, nested loops are inevitable.

```js
var cars = [{ company: "honda", colors: [{ name: "burntRed" }, { name: "springGreen" }] }, { company: "ford", colors: [{ name: "burntOrange" }, { name: "black" }] }];

cars.forEach(function (car) {
    car.colors.forEach(function (color) {
        color.name = 'new ' + color.name;
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(cars, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Yea probably should.  I wanna start using ES6 stuff to possibly

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but nested loops are usually bad because they are hard to test and reason about. I would go for a more declarative approach:

```
const appendStringToColor = (string) => (color) => ({ name: `${color.name} ${string}` });
const appendNewToColor = appendStringToColor('new');
const updateCarWithColor = (car) => ({ ...car, colors: car.colors.map(appendNewToColor) });

const updateCarsColors = (cars) => cars.map(updateCarWithColor);
```